# Empty plot... using for loop to create plot

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
G=6.674e-11 #gravitational constant
Mb=1.591e41 #mass of bulge
ps=1.616e-19 #density of stellar system
pd=4.041e-18 #density of dark matter halo
Rc=6.171e19 #Radius at 2kpc in meters
for i in np.arange(0, 6.172e19, 1e19):
    v = (np.sqrt(ps*(4/3)*np.pi*(i**2)*G))
    print(i)
    print(v)
    plt.plot(i, v, color='red')
plt.show()
```

This is giving me an empty plot. Not sure why. I've tried various techniques to no avail. Is there a function I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps you dont need a `for` loop to achieve this. `i = np.arange(0, 6.172e19, 1e19)
v = (np.sqrt(ps*(4/3)*np.pi*(i**2)*G))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you an empty plot because it assumes you're plotting lines when you're actually plotting points. There are a few ways you can fix this.

If you just want to plot the points:

```
plt.plot(i, v, color='red', marker='.')
```

or

```
plt.scatter(i, v, color='red')
```

If you want lines connecting the data points, you're going to have to modify your code more significantly. As Sathish Sanjeevi suggests, you can avoid the `for` loop altogether:

```
i = np.arange(0, 6.172e19, 1e19)
v = (np.sqrt(ps*(4/3)*np.pi*(i**2)*G))
plt.plot(i, v, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Jupyter Notebook this works for me. The missing parts for you are:

1. you need a marker in the `plot` function
2. you need `plt.show()` to display the plot between iterations

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    G=6.674e-11 #gravitational constant
    Mb=1.591e41 #mass of bulge
    ps=1.616e-19 #density of stellar system
    pd=4.041e-18 #density of dark matter halo
    Rc=6.171e19 #Radius at 2kpc in meters
    for i in np.arange(0, 6.172e19, 1e19):
        v = (np.sqrt(ps*(4/3)*np.pi*(i**2)*G))
        print(i)
        print(v)
        plt.plot(i, v, color='red', marker='o')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In short marker type is also required in plt.plot() which will assign the way to represent your data